# Take values from XML document to string array

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath

I'm attempting to take values from a XML file and put them into a string array. Here's the code I'm using to accomplish this:

```
public static string[] GetStringArray(string path)
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(path);

    var services = from service in doc.Descendants("Service")
                    select (string)service.Attribute("name");

    return services.ToArray();
}
```

But whenever I use it I get a NullReferenceException here:

```
foreach (string @string in query)
    WeatherServicesCBO.Items.Add(@string);
```

Of this method:

```
public void InitializeDropDown(string XmlFile, string xpath)
{

    //string[] services = { "Google Weather", "Yahoo! Weather", "NOAA", "WeatherBug" };
    string[] services = GetStringArray("SupportedWeatherServices.xml");
    IEnumerable<string> query = from service in services
                                orderby service.Substring(0, 1) ascending
                                select service;

    foreach (string @string in query)
        WeatherServicesCBO.Items.Add(@string);
}
```

**EDIT** Here's the XML file being used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<SupportedServices>
  <Service>
    <name>Google Weather</name>
    <active>Yes</active>
  </Service>
  <Service>
    <name>WeatherBug</name>
    <active>No</active>
  </Service>
  <Service>
    <name>Yahoo Weather</name>
    <active>No</active>
  </Service>
  <Service>
    <name>NOAA</name>
    <active>No</active>
  </Service>
</SupportedServices>
```

Comment: So did you look through the XML if every Service has a name ?  A missing one wouldn't show up when creating the `query` but when iterating it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The XML has a `name` *element*.  You are attempting to read the `name` *attribute*.  There is none so you get `null` back.  Make the appropriate changes.

```
var services = from service in doc.Descendants("Service")
                select (string)service.Element("name");
```

Answer (score 3):

`select (string)service.Attribute("name");`

"name" is not an attribute of service. it is a child element.

Answer (score 2):

`name` is not an attribute of `Service` but a child element. You should modify your `GetStringArray` query to:

```
var services = from service in doc.Descendants("Service")
               select service.Element("name").Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Get node list in Array:

```
XmlDocument xDocument;
xDocument.Load(Path);
var xArray = xDocument.SelectNodes("SupportedServices/Service/name");
```